# using ruby string interpolation while mutating object

Tags: ruby

Just encountered some strange behaviour while using string interpolation to print an object and his value after being passed to a function.

`print "#{obj} => #{function obj}"`

It outputed something similar both for `#{obj}` and `#{function obj}`

I came to the conclusion that it was because my `function` was a mutating function.
I can reproduce the output easily with :

```
def mutate_the_object(obj)
  obj.concat '1'
end
obj = '1'
print "#{obj} != #{mutate_the_object obj} != #{mutate_the_object obj} != #{obj}"
```

=> 111 != 111 != 111 != 111

Why does the string interpolation give 4 equal fields? I thought the result would be something like :

=> 1 != 11 != 111 != 111

Comment: Obviously, because the string interpolation has the lowest precedence ever.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes I did no think of that, in my mind it had to work like it would in C using `printf("%d %d %d",i,++i,++i);`
thanks

Comment: Fascinating. I always though of interpolation as a shortcut for concatenation, i.e. `'' + obj.to_s + ' != ' + mutate_the_object(obj).to_s + ' != ' + mutate_the_object(obj).to_s + ' != ' + obj.to_s + ''`. Apparently, all interpolated sections are evaluated first and then inserted.

Comment: @mudasobwa and now that I think of it, even with the lowest precedence, there should be some kind of order, i.e from left to right when interpolating variables ? or is it one big interpolation once

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye it’s like `"%s != %s != %s != %s" % [o, m(o), m(o), o]`. First the RHO array is prepared (both calls to `m(o)` are done,) then the string is being interpolated.

Comment: All arguments in RHO are the very same object. `def m(o); o << '1'; end;  o = '1'; [o, m(o), m(o), o].map(&:__id__) #⇒ [46935826870120, 46935826870120, 46935826870120, 46935826870120]`. That is _the same_ object.

Comment: **TL;DR:** mutation is a base ground of 99% of bugs and/or unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-concat) changes the object and returns it.

`def mutate_the_object` changes the object it receives as argument and returns it.

It seems the interpolated expressions are computed first, then their values are used to compute the string, in a similar fashion the C function [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) works.

The code posted in the question is equivalent to:

```
def mutate_the_object(obj)
  obj.concat '1'
end
obj = '1'
obj1 = mutate_the_object obj
obj2 = mutate_the_object obj
print "#{obj} != #{obj1} != #{obj2} != #{obj}"
```

`obj1` and `obj2` are variables that hold references to the same object as `obj`.

This can be easily proved by running:

```
print <<END
    #{obj.__id__}
    #{(mutate_the_object obj).__id__}
    #{(mutate_the_object obj).__id__}
    #{obj.__id__}
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the ISO Ruby Language Specification, the RubySpec, and the RDoc for interpolated `String` literals, and neither of the three define a specific evaluation order for interpolations. They probably *should* explicitly say that evaluation-order is undefined, but still, the fact that it *isn't* explicitly defined, means that it is implicitly undefined.

So, in other words: if your interpolations have side-effects, the order of those side-effects both with respect to each other and the time when they are inserted into the string is unspecified, and what you are observing is a perfectly legal implementation of the spec.

From what I can tell, (at least) any of the following results is legal:

```
'1 != 11 != 111 != 1'
'1 != 11 != 111 != 11'
'1 != 11 != 111 != 111'
'1 != 111 != 11 != 1'
'1 != 111 != 11 != 11'
'1 != 111 != 11 != 111'
'1 != 111 != 111 != 1'
'1 != 111 != 111 != 11'
'1 != 111 != 111 != 111'
'11 != 11 != 111 != 1'
'11 != 11 != 111 != 11'
'11 != 11 != 111 != 111'
'11 != 111 != 11 != 1'
'11 != 111 != 11 != 11'
'11 != 111 != 11 != 111'
'11 != 111 != 111 != 1'
'11 != 111 != 111 != 11'
'11 != 111 != 111 != 111'
'111 != 11 != 111 != 1'
'111 != 11 != 111 != 11'
'111 != 11 != 111 != 111'
'111 != 111 != 11 != 1'
'111 != 111 != 11 != 11'
'111 != 111 != 11 != 111'
'111 != 111 != 111 != 1'
'111 != 111 != 111 != 11'
'111 != 111 != 111 != 111'
```